# What is the type GUID?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm translating a C++ Windows API to a delphi *.pas file.

I have this [C Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returned by a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
typedef struct _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS {
  WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE      HostedNetworkState;
  GUID                           IPDeviceID;
  DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS              wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
  DOT11_PHY_TYPE                 dot11PhyType;
  ULONG                          ulChannelFrequency;
  DWORD                          dwNumberOfPeers;
  WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE PeerList[1];
} WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS, *PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS;
```

I translated to this:

```
type
_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS = record 
  HostedNetworkState : WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATE;
  IPDeviceID : GUID;
  wlanHostedNetworkBSSID : DOT11_MAC_ADDRESS;
  dot11PhyType : DOT11_PHY_TYPE;
  ulChannelFrequency : ULONG;
  dwNumberOfPeers : DWORD;
  PeerList : Array [0..1] of WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE;
end;
WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS = _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS;
PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS = _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS;
```

but I not found on MSDN reference what is this `GUID` type of `IPDeviceID`
it is a primitive type? how do I hold this value?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag because really this is a pure Delphi question

Comment: A GUID means a Globally Unique Identifier, it's basically a very large auto-generated unique value. In the context of the question you're asking about, the use of it is to uniquely identify a specific device installed onto your computer. Devices installed in windows have a GUID used in lots of places. Think of it as the unique serial number for a particular hardware or kernel-level object. In this case your WLAN card's id number.  Delphi supports GUID literals in code, if you see something like this it is also a GUID: `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Delphi equivalent is [`TGUID`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TGUID).

The Delphi documentation contains some [examples of how to use this type and its associated helper function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/UsingGUIDs_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: @WarrenP why is this a comment to David's answer? Why not an answer itself or at least a comment to the question?

Answer (score 6):

[GUID structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also known as UUID, is a widely used 128-bit value type which represents globally unique identifiers.

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

A quick check reveals that Delphi already has this type, named `TGuid` in module `System`.